# What's the difference between client id and tenant id?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Azure requires multiple IDs to create application ServicePrincipal credentials.

What's the difference between the `client id` and `tenant id`?

Why does Azure require separate IDs?

Comment: A client id identifies a *client.*  A tenant id identifies a *tenant.*  You can have multiple clients on a given tenant database.  Think: software that can handle multiple companies (i.e. tenants), each with their own clients.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

An application ID is the ID of the specific application you have created in Azure Active Directory, you will likely have many applications for different purposes. Each application can have different users assigned access, different criteria for access (MFA, conditional access etc.) and will be configured to authenticate users for different real applications or purposes. Each Azure AD application has a unique ID, and this ID is what you give your application to use to talk to it when processing logins etc.

All of your applications sit within an Azure Active Directory instance, or as MS like to call it, a tenant. The tenant ID identifies which Azure AD instance the application sits under, so Azure knows where to look when you request things using that applicaiton ID.

I suppose in theory if Applicaiton IDs were unique globally then you could work out the tenant from the App ID, but that isn't how MS set it up.

Comment: As an additional clarification: client id == application id. Registered applications get a unique client id, and the Application and Service Principal objects in AAD reference it.